# regex: How to replace curly brackets in the html content except the curly brackets inside style tags?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a html content as below. I want to replace "`{`" with "`{{`" and "`}`" with "`}}`". But I want to retain the single curly brackets in the style tags.

Note: I'm using javascript and I read the html content from the database since it is stored in db.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    p {
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>My name is {name}</p>
    <p>My age is {age}</p>
</body>
```

Expected output is as below.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    p {
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>My name is {{name}}</p>
    <p>My age is {{age}}</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you *have* to use a regular expression?

Comment: Hi @CertainPerformance, Yes.

Comment: Better if str.repalce() can be used with a regular expression.

Comment: @asankasri You can use EditPlus to make your text or content as you want. ex:) `replace /`  `{ -> {{` & `}</p>` -> `}}</p>` & `p {{\n` -> `p {{\n`. (Regular expression)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this regex will help:

```
str.replace(/\{(\w+)\}/gm, "{{$1}}")
```

See [this](https://regex101.com/r/9Cq3nD/2) at Regex101

```js
let str = `<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    p {
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>My name is {name}</p>
    <p>My age is {age}</p>
</body>`;

console.log(str.replace(/\{(\w+)\}/gm, "{{$1}}"))
```

This regular expression will search for any single alphanumeric string surrounded in curly brackets. The parentheses capture this inner "word". All this is replaced by the captured word surrounded by double curly brackets.

Any opening curly bracket followed by a space or a line break will not match.

Comment: Thank you for your solution!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
let str = `<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    p {
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>My name is {name}</p>
    <p>My age is {age}</p>
</body>`;
console.log(str.replace(/({|})(?=[^.{1}\s*])/g, "$1$1"));
```